# Constraint headers format in CHR

Tags: constraint-programming, constraint-handling-rules

I'm new to CHR and I was wondering if it makes sense to have have functions as arguments for constraint heads in a rule. I know that in the body of the rule this is possible.

E.g. Is `C(X-Y)` legal here?

```
C(X), C(X-Y), C(Y) => C(X * Y)
```